# How do I prevent the user from typing new lines in a contentEditable element?

Tags: javascript

I made my div element contentEditable so that the user can edit its contents:

```
<div contentEditable='true' id='myDiv'>
    This content can be edited.
</div>
```

However, I'd like to prevent the user from typing new lines into the div element. I've tried preventing the default action of keydown events to no avail:

```
var container = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function tryToPreventNewLines(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:
            container.blur();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

myDiv.addEventListener(
    'keydown', tryToPreventNewLines);
myDiv.addEventListener(
    'change', tryToPreventNewLines);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwmspdm4/

In this case, the user can produce several new lines by hitting the enter key while within the div and not letting go of the enter key.

Comment: David a div element is not really intended for editing so the prevent default or return false does not work. I changed your fiddle to use an input end then your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/pwmspdm4/3/

Comment: @David your code works fine on my chorme  40.0.2214.93 m

Comment: @Van: `preventDefault` works just fine on current browsers at the least (didn't test older ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `container.blur()` call; if you move that out of the handling of the event with a `setTimeout`, the code works (prevents the user creating a newline, and blurs the container):

```
function tryToPreventNewLines(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function() {
                container.blur();
            }, 0);
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwmspdm4/1/)

Of course, I'm assuming you *want* to blur the container when they press Enter. If not, just remove that line entirely.

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.

---

Below you note that on Chrome, holding down Enter continues to add newlines, even with the above. The only way I see to prevent that is to control the `contentEditable` property:

```
var container = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function tryToPreventNewLines(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:
            e.preventDefault();
            this.contentEditable = false; // No longer editable
            this.blur();                  // Remove selection box on Firefox
            return false;
    }
    // Removed the `return true;` here; it was a no-op
}

function enableEdit() {
    this.contentEditable = true;          // Make it editable
    this.focus();                         // And put the cursor in it
}

// Just for max compatibility, added the third argument below;
// some browsers still require it
myDiv.addEventListener(
    'keydown', tryToPreventNewLines, false);
myDiv.addEventListener(
    'change', tryToPreventNewLines, false);
myDiv.addEventListener(
    'click', enableEdit, false);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwmspdm4/6/)

Comment: Thanks, I think the user can still input new lines in Chrome by pressing the enter key and not releasing though ...

Comment: @DavidFaux: Huh, sure enough. Did you need the `blur`? E.g., are you using Enter to mean "I'm done editing"?

Comment: @DavidFaux: If so, the edit to the answer seems to solve the problem.